# Angular link array of number with scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Buttons (ui.bootstrap.buttons) from [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and
I want to link the state of the button with a variable in a array.

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('test')
.controller('btest',
    ['$scope',
     '$log',
     function ($scope, $log) {
         $log.info("controller Loaded!");
         var checkboxes = [false,false];

         $scope.pos1 = checkboxes[0];
         $scope.pos2 = checkboxes[1];

     }])
```

This is a part of the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<button type="button" class="col-md-1 btn btn-primary" ng-model="pos1" uib-btn-checkbox>B1</button>
<button type="button" class="col-md-1 btn btn-primary" ng-model="pos2" uib-btn-checkbox>B2</button>
</div>
```

By clicking a button it does not change the value inside checkboxes array but only of his variable.

For example: after the click on `"B1" pos1=true`while`checkboxes[0]=false`.

I can force the update of the vector using an update function like this:

```
$scope.update = function(index) {
             checkboxes[index] = !checkboxes[index];
}
```

But I think it is not the right way.

Can someone explain me how I can link the state of button with his variable inside checkboxes array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
angular.module('test')
.controller('btest',
  ['$scope',
   '$log',
   function ($scope, $log) {
     $log.info("controller Loaded!");
     $scope.checkboxes = [false,false];

  }])


<div class="row">
  <button type="button" class="col-md-1 btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkboxes[0]" uib-btn-checkbox>B1</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-md-1 btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkboxes[1]" uib-btn-checkbox>B2</button>
</div>
```

`uib-btn-checkbox` will always set the value of whatever is in your ng-model. So I've put the checkboxes array on the scope and used it instead.

The confusion that you seem to have is that you expected `pos1` and `pos2` to hold the reference to your checkbox array values. JavaScript (and most other languages) don't work like that. So your code would be equivalent to:

```
angular.module('test')
.controller('btest',
  ['$scope',
   '$log',
   function ($scope, $log) {
     $log.info("controller Loaded!");

     $scope.pos1 = false;
     $scope.pos2 = false;

 }])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better if done in this way:

```
<div class="row">
  <button type="button" class="col-md-1 btn btn-primary" ng-repeat="checkbox in checkboxes" ng-click="checkbox.isChecked = !checkbox.isChecked" ng-model="checkbox.isChecked" uib-btn-checkbox>{{checkbox.text}}</button>
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
.controller('btest',
  ['$scope',
   '$log',
   function ($scope, $log) {
     $scope.checkboxes = [
       {
          text: "B1"
       },
       {
          text: "B2"
       }
     ];
     $scope.checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
       checkbox.isChecked = false;
     });
 }])
```

This avoids code repetition, and also makes it easier to maintain!